# Unable to send Hash Tag symbol (#) in the SMS body in Kannel

Tags: php, kannel

I am trying to send a message that includes **hash tag symbol(#)** in SMS body using **Kannel**. But unfortunately it is not sending. It gives **403** status and "**Not routable. Do not try again.**" status description. For sending sms message I also use **PHP script**. Maybe it is related with php script. How Can I resolve this problem? Is there any way to fix it?

I am sending below message:

```
*100*1238#
```

Comment: If you think it might be related to your PHP script, you'll have to show it to us.

Comment: I found a another solution for this. Instead of # sign I am using ```%23```. Message looks like this ```*100*1238%23```